# TypeError in Countvectorizer scikit-learn: Expected string or buffer

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am trying to solve a classification problem. when I feed the text to CountVectorizer it gives error:

> expected string or buffer.

Is anything wrong with my dataset as it contains message mixture of number and word even special character is also in message.

Sample how does message look like is following:

```
0         I have not received my gifts which I ordered ok
1                 hth her wells idyll McGill kooky bbc.co
2                                   test test test 1 test
3                                                    test
4                         hello where is my reward points
5       hi, can you get koovs coupons or vouchers here...
```

Here is the code I used to do classification:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
df = pd.read_excel('training_data.xlsx')
X_train = df.message
print X_train.shape
map_class_label = {'checkin':0, 'greeting':1,'more reward options':2,'noclass':3, 'other':4,'points':5,
                           'referral points':6,'snapbill':7, 'thanks':8,'voucher not working':9,'voucher':10}
df['label_num'] = df['Final Category'].map(map_class_label)
y_train = df.label_num
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False,decode_error='ignore')
X_train_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Comment: @jezrael Final Category is class label (Text data)  corresponding to each message which I change to numeric value via mapping to label_num column. Its not missing in dataset I just didn't show. as the problem occurred when I tried to fit and transform message using countvectorizer.

Comment: And my solution works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert column `message` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), because in data are some numeric values:

```
df = pd.read_excel('training_data.xlsx')
df['message'] = df['message'].values.astype('unicode')
...
...
```

Comment: can't able to convert due to UnicodeEncodeError error. I also tried df.message.apply(str).

Comment: Hmmm, i have one idea - is possible set in Excel column `message` to string?

Comment: Than you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error by passing only one string, like this:

```
cv.fit_transform('Making my way down,')
```

Instead you have to pass a list with strings, like this:

```
cv.fit_transform(['Making my way down,', ])
```